# Envoy routing traffic to unhealthy servers

Tags: python, google-kubernetes-engine, grpc, envoyproxy, kubernetes-health-check

I have a grpc server running in python. The flow of request is `client => gce-ingress => envoy => grpc-server`. The deployment yaml are listed below.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: envoy-deployment
  
  labels:
    app: envoy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: envoy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: envoy
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: envoy
        image: envoyproxy/envoy:v1.22.5
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9901
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            port: 9901
            httpHeaders:
            - name: x-envoy-livenessprobe
              value: healthz
            path: /healthz
            scheme: HTTPS
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            port: 9901
            httpHeaders:
              - name: x-envoy-livenessprobe
                value: healthz
            path: /healthz
            scheme: HTTPS
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          mountPath: /etc/envoy
        - name: certs
          mountPath: /etc/ssl/envoy
      volumes:
      - name: config
        configMap:
          name: envoy-conf
      - name: certs
        secret:
          secretName: secret-tls
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: envoy-deployment-service
  
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"ports": {"443":"envoy-app-backend-config"}}'
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
spec:
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 443
    targetPort: 9901
  selector:
    app: envoy
  type: NodePort
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-server
  
  labels:
    app: server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: server
    spec:
      containers:
        name: server
        image: gcr.io/project/image:latest
        command: ["python3" , "/var/app/api/main.py"]
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /secrets/gcloud-auth
          name: gcloud-auth
          readOnly: true
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
      volumes:
      - name: gcloud-auth
        secret:
          secretName: gcloud
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-server-headless
  
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: server
  ports:
    - name: grpc
      port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
      protocol: TCP
```

My envoy config looks like this:-

```
metadata:
  name: envoy-conf
  
data:
  envoy.yaml: |
    admin:
      access_log_path: /tmp/admin_access.log
      address:
        socket_address: { address: 127.0.0.1, port_value: 9902 }

    static_resources:
      listeners:
        - name: listener_0
          address:
            socket_address: { address:  0.0.0.0, port_value: 9901 }
          filter_chains:
            - filters:
              - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
                typed_config:
                  "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
                  codec_type: auto
                  access_log:
                  - name: envoy.access_loggers.file
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.file.v3.FileAccessLog
                      path: "/dev/stdout"
                  stat_prefix: ingress_https
                  route_config:
                    name: local_route
                    virtual_hosts:
                      - name: envoy_service
                        domains: ["*"]
                        routes:
                        #- match:
                        #   prefix: "/healthz"
                        #  direct_response: { status: 200, body: { inline_string: "ok it is working now" } }
                        - match:
                           prefix: "/heal"
                          direct_response: { status: 200, body: { inline_string: "ok heal is working now" } }
                        
                        - match:
                            prefix: "/envoy/"
                          route: {
                            prefix_rewrite: "/",
                            cluster: envoy_service
                          }
    
                        - match:
                            prefix: "/"
                          route: {
                            prefix_rewrite: "/",
                            cluster: envoy_service
                          }
                        cors:
                          allow_origin_string_match:
                            - prefix: "*"
                          allow_methods: GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS
                          allow_headers: keep-alive,user-agent,cache-control,content-type,content-transfer-encoding,custom-header-1,x-accept-content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-response-streaming,x-user-agent,x-grpc-web,grpc-timeout
                          max_age: "1728000"
                          expose_headers: custom-header-1,grpc-status,grpc-message
                  http_filters:
                    - name: envoy.filters.http.cors
                      typed_config:
                        "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.cors.v3.Cors
                    - name: envoy.filters.http.grpc_web
                      typed_config:
                        "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.grpc_web.v3.GrpcWeb
                    - name: envoy.filters.http.health_check
                      typed_config:
                        "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.health_check.v3.HealthCheck
                        pass_through_mode: false
                        headers:
                        - name: ":path"
                          exact_match: "/healthz"
                        - name: "x-envoy-livenessprobe"
                          exact_match: "healthz"
                    - name: envoy.filters.http.router
                      typed_config:
                        "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router
                    
              transport_socket:
                  name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
                  typed_config:
                    "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.DownstreamTlsContext
                    require_client_certificate: false
                    common_tls_context:
                      tls_certificates:
                      - certificate_chain:
                          filename: /etc/ssl/envoy/tls.crt
                        private_key:
                          filename: /etc/ssl/envoy/tls.key
                      alpn_protocols: [ "h2,http/1.1" ]
      clusters:
        - name: envoy_service
          connect_timeout: 0.50s
          type: strict_dns
          http2_protocol_options: {}
          lb_policy: round_robin
          common_lb_config:
              healthy_panic_threshold:
                value: 0.0
          load_assignment:
            cluster_name: envoy_service
            endpoints:
              - lb_endpoints:
                - endpoint:
                    address:
                      socket_address:
                        address: app-server-headless
                        port_value: 8000
          health_checks:
            timeout: 1s
            interval: 5s
            unhealthy_threshold: 2
            healthy_threshold: 2
            grpc_health_check:
                service_name: envoy_service.Health
```

Everything seems to be working fine except when a new version `app-server` deployment is done. The request starts to fail during the interval where new pod being ready and old pod being terminated. The grpc client request fails with error `no healthy upstream UNAVAILABLE, (14, 'unavailable')`. This only happens during the time the older revision of pod is being terminated. Should envoy automatically handle this? What additional config is required?

The api server has a `grpc health check` and `handle_sigterm`  method which gracefully shuts down the server in case a shutdown signal is received. The api grpc server and the health server runs on same port.

```
class HealthServicer(health_pb2_grpc.HealthServicer):
    def __init__(self):
        self.status = health_pb2.HealthCheckResponse.SERVING

def Check(self, request, context):
    response = health_pb2.HealthCheckResponse()
    response.status = self.status
    LOG.info(f"server is healthy with response {response}")
    return response

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    server = grpc.server(
        futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=40),
        interceptors=(AuthInterceptor(access_key),),
    )
    api_pb2_grpc.add_APIServiceServicer_to_server(
        APIServiceServicer(args.env), server
    )
    health_pb2_grpc.add_HealthServicer_to_server(HealthServicer(), server)
    server.add_insecure_port("0.0.0.0:8000")
    server.start()
    LOG.info("server started")

    def handle_sigterm(*_):
        LOG.error("Received shutdown signal")
        # do something
        all_rpc_done_event = server.stop(10)
        all_rpc_done_event.wait(10)
        LOG.error("Shut down gracefully")
   signal(SIGTERM, handle_sigterm)
   signal(SIGINT, handle_sigterm)
   server.wait_for_termination()
```

The thing is that the errors thrown at the client is correlated to time passed in `server.stop()` and `event.wait()` method. If I increase the time to 30s then I see more number of errors as compared to when time is 10s. Shouldn't envoy's health check automatically detect unhealthy pods and stop routing traffic to it? What am I missing here?